# PHP and DB connections replace with mysqli from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
$db = mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$q = "select*from tablename";
$qry = mysql_query($q);
```

can you please help me to convert this mysql query to mysqli

Comment: There are so many solutions available on net

Comment: @Ashu - What's wrong to have a solution on SO? Do you have a duplicate reference?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel this question posted without any research.

Comment: @Ashu - The same is true for almost all popular questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
// mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "your_db");

// mysqli_select_db(connection, dbname);
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, "dbname");

$q = "select*from tablename";

// mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);
$qry = mysqli_query($con, $q);
```

Refer below docs

1. [PHP Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
2. [w3schools Mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)